# Can Reg win the fight against Ozen in Hello Abyss mode?

Tags: made-in-abyss-binary-star

In *Made in Abyss: Binary Star Falling into Darkness*, there's a boss fight between Reg and Ozen in the second layer of Hello Abyss mode. When I lost the fight a cutscene played and the story progressed like the anime the game is based on.

Is it possible to win the fight against Ozen in Hello Abyss mode? If so, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the video below shows Reg beating Ozen in Hello Abyss mode. The same cutscene will play regardless of whether you win or lose the fight.